# How use array as const to specify possible indexes in index signature TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to make an array, which will specify, which strings will index properties inside object and that object properties only contain functions.

What I do understand, is that I can create union type from just array:

My working case is a reducer action (instruction) in React reducer (but it can be used elsewhere):

```
const InstructionsArray = [
    'HANDLE_BUTTON_CONVERT_INPUT',
    'HANDLE_CHECKBOX_CONVERT_ON_INPUT',
    'HANDLE_CHECKBOX_DISPLAY_TAGS',
    'HANDLE_TEXTAREA_INPUT',
    'HANDLE_RUNTIME'
] as const;
```

Then I have type object with property:

```
instruction: typeof InstructionsArray[number]
```

Of course, normal array would allow us to use any string as indexes, but since we casted it as `const`, it now only allows for the strings, we specified in array.

What I actually want, is to have an object, which will have some property names as `string` and all properties will have value of `function`. I would like to specify only those property names (`string`), but as every value will be a `function`, I would not like to specify it more than once, so it can be taken as granted.

Current code looks like that:

```
const changersLabels = [
    'inventory',
    'quest'
] as const;
```

But the 'same' way does not work on object like that:

```
keyboardRouter(changers: {[key:typeof changersLabels[number]:Function]}) {

    //some stuff

}
```

What am I doing wrong and is that even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you just want a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) where the keys are `typeof changersLabels[number]` and the properties are all `Function`:

```
function keyboardRouter(changers: { [K in typeof changersLabels[number]]: Function }) {
  changers.inventory // Function
  changers.quest // Function
}
```

A mapped type looks a little like a type with [an index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), but that only works where the index is of type `string` or of type `number`.  For other types like a union of string literals, you need a mapped type with the `in` operator.

Which could be slightly refactored to give a name to your keys and to use the built-in [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
type ChangersLabels = typeof changersLabels[number];
function keyboardRouter2(changers: Record<ChangersLabels, Function>) {
  changers.inventory // Function
  changers.quest // Function
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBMAWBDMBzApgJwgGUQIzQBsIYBeGAbQCgYYByASzADc0woQMBPOgGhvoBHAK5podGFQC6MRCVCQoAbipUAZsLDAoDcDADWaLnhCIMAEwBKIYVEwAKBMnRYAXDADelANIwmMKC4ABzQQNTgkVEwcfCIICjBhAFsCDCkpdwAxTW1dMBgAXwBKTwEnKKwAOiZWdk4uGAB6RphsrR1wMsiXCEqRMVhm1pyOsCoC1UCQmABhbujcAmIyAODQ8PKexbiE5NSpFQ12vIMjEzMrGzsMACZHebcYSzRQCwAeOecF2OJeYePwAA+EoeLpfKo1NgcbhNFptXKdWibaJ9UTQWH-BFjCZAA)